# Find the radius of curvature at any point $(r, \theta)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, curvature

Find the radius of curvature at any point $(r, \theta)$ for the curve $a^2 = r^2\cos (2\theta)$

My Attempt:
$$a^2 = r^2 \cos (2\theta)$$
$$r^2 = a^2 \sec (2\theta)$$
Differentiating both sides
$$2rr_{1} = 2a^2 sec(2\theta)\cdot \tan (2\theta)$$
$$rr_{1} = a^2 \sec (2\theta) \tan (2\theta)$$

Comment: $r = a \sqrt {\sec 2\theta}$. Find $r', r''$ and plug into the formula for $K$. $R = 1 / K$.

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinates, the radius of curvature is given by (have a look [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadiusofCurvature.html))$$\large R=\frac{\left(r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2\right)^{3/2}}{\left|r^2+2\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2-r\left(\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}\right)\right|}$$